# Cannot set checkpoint dir when running Connected Component example

Tags: python, pyspark, graphframes

This is the Connected Components [example](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#connected-components) by `graphframe`:

```py
from graphframes.examples import Graphs
g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph

result = g.connectedComponents()
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

In the document, they said:

> NOTE: With GraphFrames 0.3.0 and later releases, the default Connected Components algorithm requires setting a Spark checkpoint directory. Users can revert to the old algorithm using connectedComponents.setAlgorithm("graphx").

So this is my full code `connected.py` with `setCheckpointDir`:

```py
import pyspark

sc = pyspark.SparkContext().getOrCreate()

sc.addPyFile("/home/username/.ivy2/jars/graphframes_graphframes-0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12.jar")

from graphframes.examples import Graphs

sc.setCheckpointDir("graphframes_cps")

g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph

result = g.connectedComponents()
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

And run with this command:

```
spark-submit connected.py --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

Then it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username//test/spark/connected.py", line 11, in <module>
    sc.setCheckpointDir("graphframes_cps")
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 975, in setCheckpointDir
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.setCheckpointDir.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the example of Connected Components by `graphframes`:

```py
from graphframes.examples import Graphs
g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph

result = g.connectedComponents()
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

I will get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Checkpoint directory is not set. Please set it first using sc.setCheckpointDir().
```

That means I have not set the `checkpointDir` yet. Then add that line:

```py
sc.setCheckpointDir(dirName="/home/username/graphframes_cps")

result = g.connectedComponents()
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

The error I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username//test/spark/connected.py", line 11, in <module>
    sc.setCheckpointDir("graphframes_cps")
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 975, in setCheckpointDir
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.setCheckpointDir.

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o176.setCheckpointDir.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From huycomputer/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

There are others error lines below that I didn't notice but that is the root problem. I didn't start the HDFS so `pyspark` cannot connect to `localhost:9000` which is the HDFS service port.

So after I run `start-dfs.sh`, it works as expected. But I still don't know how to use the local folder. This is `localhost:9870` and in the `"/home/username/graphframes_cps"` path after I run the example a few times.

[image]

So this is my full code, I use Jupyter Notebook so it already start a `SparkContext`, I just need to use `sc` variable to run `setCheckpointDir()`:

```py
from graphframes.examples import Graphs
g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph
sc.setCheckpointDir(dirName="/home/dhuy237/graphframes_cps")

result = g.connectedComponents()
result.select("id", "component").orderBy("component").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------------+
| id|   component|
+---+------------+
|  b|412316860416|
|  c|412316860416|
|  e|412316860416|
|  f|412316860416|
|  d|412316860416|
|  a|412316860416|
+---+------------+
```